# Clean out, or reset test-database with Rspec and Mongoid 5.0 on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When I run my rspec tests, many fail due to stale data in my mongodb database. AFAIK it is far better to test with a clean database.

How can I clean and/or re-seed the database before each test?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem to accomplish this task.

From their documentation:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy= :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

As you are using Mongoid ORM, you may also need to specify it explicitly:

```
# How to setup your ORM explicitly
DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
```

#### Update:

I see an [open issue for MongoID 5](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/378)

To make it work, you can monkey patch the Mongo Ruby driver class as mentioned in the issue.

```
module Mongo
  class Collection
    class View
      def remove_all
        remove(0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Athough it's not a great solution!

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work with database cleaner, the mongoid 5.0.0.beta has removed the method "remove_all" so does'nt work.

Comment: gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/moped/truncation_base.rb:14:in `block in clean': undefined method `remove_all' for #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x00000007c11a18> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I see an open issue: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/378

To make it work, you can monkey patch the Mongo Ruby driver class. Athough its not a great solution!

Comment: Why downvote this? Care to comment? Constructive comments are welcome before downvoting without a comment! 
So that I can update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The fix to the problem is there in the master branch of database_cleaner(1.4.1) gem. Install the gem from master to fix the problem (until there is the version bump). Expected to get fixed in next version.

```
gem 'database_cleaner', :git => 'https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner.git'
```

Comment: which version of `database_cleaner ` are you using?

Comment: i was using 1.4.1 but when i installed database_cleaner using master. It worked.